# My query doesn't show all results in my database

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I currently have 3 records in my database that should show up, but I only see 2 of the 3.

Just so you understand what is going on:

subscriber 1 & 2 have campaign id 1 and subscriber 3 has campaign id 2
however both subscribers belong to campaigns created by the same account.
So, what I am trying to accomplish is to show the account holder who has subscribed to their campaigns.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
def get_campaign_subscribers():
    # Get authenticated user campaigns and create a list
    campaigns = Campaign.query.filter_by(user_id=g.user.id).all()
    campaign_list = []

    if campaigns:
        for c in campaigns:
            campaign_list.append(c.id)

    for i in campaign_list:
        return get_subscribers(i)


def get_subscribers(campaign_id):
    subscribers = Subscriber.query.filter_by(campaign_id=campaign_id).all()
    return subscribers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or perhaps, try combining 2 into 1 simple function using `join`:

```
def get_subscribers_by_user():
    subscribers = Subscriber.query.\
                             join(Campaign).\
                             filter(Campaign.user_id == g.user.id).all()
    return subscribers
```

Comment: @rhymiz, glad it helps, we've all been through this stage ;)

Answer (score 0):

You only return the first `compaigns` in the `campaign_list`, since in the first loop you make the function return. Try this:

```
def get_campaign_subscribers():
    # Get authenticated user campaigns and create a list
    campaigns = Campaign.query.filter_by(user_id=g.user.id).all()
    campaign_list = []

    if campaigns:
        for c in campaigns:
            campaign_list.append(c.id)
    # return a list which is result of get_subscribers by passing through items in campaign_list
    return map(get_subscribers, campaign_list)    



def get_subscribers(campaign_id):
    subscribers = Subscriber.query.filter_by(campaign_id=campaign_id).all()
    return subscribers
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed part of my problem.
But now my template shows up with empty records in the table.

The amount of records is correct, but no data for them.